# AngularJS: Switch model value does not affect on UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a directive and initiated some models in `link:` method, then bind a click event on `<a>` tag of template. Where scope models switches it's values to each-other.

When I see model values in console, seems it's working fine. But does not reflect on UI.

Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gp32g7sr/7/

Comment: add `scope.$apply()` at the end of the directive code. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/tnetresm/)

Comment: scope.apply() will work .. the above comment is correct. you need to kill $digest using scope.$apply() that no more watches on the change.

Comment: @valverde93 thank you so much, `scope.$apply()` is working. This is what I was looking for. Answer this below to close! Update: http://jsfiddle.net/gp32g7sr/9/

Comment: @vinaykrsharma you're welcome! Mr pankajparkar has answered below too and it's ready to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to `$apply` on a scope to run digest cycle. Changing scope variable from an events doesn't run angular digest cycle we need to manually run it.

**Link Fn**

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.activeContinent = 'Asia';
        scope.altContinent = 'America';
        element.find('a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var x = scope.altContinent;
            scope.altContinent = scope.activeContinent;
            scope.activeContinent = x;
            document.querySelector('#log')
                .innerHTML = scope.activeContinent + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + scope.altContinent;
            //$compile(document.querySelector('#log'))(scope);
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gp32g7sr/8/)